# Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [layers]

Tags: json, elasticsearch, jq, tcpdump, tshark

When trying to send my json formatted tcpdump to elasticsearch, I get the following error:

```
curl -X PUT --data-binary @myjson 'localhost:9200/_bulk?pretty'
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "parsing_exception",
        "reason" : "Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [layers].",
        "line" : 1,
        "col" : 95
      }
    ],
    "type" : "parsing_exception",
    "reason" : "Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [layers].",
    "line" : 1,
    "col" : 95
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

The json file was obtained using tshark with the "-T json" option.
The json file was modified using jq with the filter "{index: .[]}" and the option -c since elasticsearch requires an entry to fit in a single line.
I am using elasticsearch 5.5.1 with the standard configuration.
jsonformatter marks the json object as valid.

A json object that produces the error looks as follows:

```
{"index":{"_index":"packets-2017-08-04","_type":"pcap_file","_score":null,"_source":{"layers":{"frame":{"frame.encap_type":"25","frame.time":"Aug  5, 2001 13:10:06.559762000 CEST","frame.offset_shift":"0.000000000","frame.time_epoch":"1501773006.559765000","frame.time_delta":"0.000000000","frame.time_delta_displayed":"0.000000000","frame.time_relative":"0.000000000","frame.number":"1","frame.len":"200","frame.cap_len":"200","frame.marked":"0","frame.ignored":"0","frame.protocols":"sll:ethertype:ip:tcp:data"},"sll":{"sll.pkttype":"4","sll.hatype":"65135","sll.halen":"0","sll.etype":"0x00000800"},"ip":{"ip.version":"4","ip.hdr_len":"20","ip.dsfield":"0x00000010","ip.dsfield_tree":{"ip.dsfield.dscp":"4","ip.dsfield.ecn":"0"},"ip.len":"184","ip.id":"0x000093f2","ip.flags":"0x00000002","ip.flags_tree":{"ip.flags.rb":"0","ip.flags.df":"1","ip.flags.mf":"0"},"ip.frag_offset":"0","ip.ttl":"64","ip.proto":"6","ip.checksum":"0x0000ef4b","ip.checksum.status":"2","ip.src":"0.0.00","ip.addr":"0.0.0.0","ip.src_host":"0.0.0.0","ip.host":"0.0.0.0","ip.dst":"0.0.0.0","ip.dst_host":"0.0.0.0","Source GeoIP: Germany":{"ip.geoip.src_country":"Germany","ip.geoip.country":"Germany","ip.geoip.src_city":"Frankfurt, 1","ip.geoip.city":"Berlin, 1","ip.geoip.src_asnum":"123","ip.geoip.asnum":"123","ip.geoip.src_lat":"701","ip.geoip.lat":"523,01","ip.geoip.src_lon":"2313,4","ip.geoip.lon":"12,13"},"Destination GeoIP: Germany":{"ip.geoip.dst_country":"Germany","ip.geoip.country":"Germany","ip.geoip.dst_asnum":"123","ip.geoip.asnum":"123","ip.geoip.dst_lat":"3321","ip.geoip.lat":"41","ip.geoip.dst_lon":"1","ip.geoip.lon":"2"}},"tcp":{"tcp.srcport":"41","tcp.dstport":"124","tcp.port":"234","tcp.stream":"3","tcp.len":"134","tcp.seq":"1","tcp.nxtseq":"133","tcp.ack":"4","tcp.hdr_len":"32","tcp.flags":"0x00000018","tcp.flags_tree":{"tcp.flags.res":"0","tcp.flags.ns":"0","tcp.flags.cwr":"0","tcp.flags.ecn":"0","tcp.flags.urg":"0","tcp.flags.ack":"1","tcp.flags.push":"1","tcp.flags.reset":"0","tcp.flags.syn":"0","tcp.flags.fin":"0","tcp.flags.str":"Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·APÂ·Â·Â·"},"tcp.window_size_value":"223","tcp.window_size":"31","tcp.window_size_scalefactor":"-1","tcp.checksum":"0x0000b79c","tcp.checksum.status":"1","tcp.urgent_pointer":"0","tcp.options":"123","tcp.options_tree":{"No-Operation (NOP)":{"tcp.options.type":"1","tcp.options.type_tree":{"tcp.options.type.copy":"0","tcp.options.type.class":"0","tcp.options.type.number":"1"}},"Timestamps: TSval 1875055084, TSecr 5726840":{"tcp.option_kind":"8","tcp.option_len":"10","tcp.options.timestamp.tsval":"185084","tcp.options.timestamp.tsecr":"1116840"}},"tcp.analysis":{"tcp.analysis.bytes_in_flight":"123","tcp.analysis.push_bytes_sent":"133"}},"data":{"data.data":"01:01:02","data.len":"265"}}}}}
```

My question is: What is wrong with this json, so that elasticsearch rejects it?

Comment: The line that you show as the first line of the JSON suggests that the input to curl is not valid JSON, so maybe that's the problem.  In any case, please revise your question in accordance with the guidelines at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I updated my question and hope that it now fits the guideline. It includes a sample json that produces the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really a jq problem - **Unknown key for a START_OBJECT** is an elasticsearch error.  The **`[layers]`** is a hint that the problem is in the object there which unfortunately was elided in the problem description so there's really not much to go on here.

Since the jq filter you specified is just `{index:.[]}`, jq is doing nothing to the part of the json elasticsearch is complaining about.  If your workflow is expecting jq to correct that portion somehow you'll need to investigate the data closer and use a more sophisticated filter.

For reference, the [elasticsearch test suite](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/43efcffcc217f5e49ed15593bc3156c2b4db1c73/modules/reindex/src/test/resources/rest-api-spec/test/reindex/20_validation.yml#L17-L23) contains an example of this particular error:

```
---
"junk in source fails":
  - do:
      catch: /Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in \[junk\]./
      reindex:
        body:
          source:
            junk: {}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The json I send to elasticsearch via curl should be fine since jsonformatter marks it as valid json. Thanks for the input!

Comment: I added a json object that produces the error to my initial question.